# What's the difference between doing alloc and class_createInstance

Tags: objective-c

Wondering, what is the difference between creating a class with:

```
Class clazz = [NSString class];
[clazz alloc];
```

and

```
class_createInstance(clazz,0);
```

Answer (score 10):

Basically, you shouldn't be using `class_createInstance()` unless you know enough about what you're doing that you can answer this question yourself.

Calling `class_createInstance()` bypasses any special cases that have been implemented in `+alloc`.  If you try it with `NSString`, you will get an `NSString` instance, not an instance of the private placeholder class that is the proper target for whatever `-init...` message you want to send it.

Comment: +1 especially for "unless you ... can answer this question yourself"

Comment: Yes, and thanks also to the other comments here, and the macdev irc on freenode, I've started learning about the class clusters, to which I believe you're eluding to... Very interesting stuff...

Answer (score 3):

There is a description here:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/111527-class-createinstance-with-nsarray-nsdictionary.html

Basically, class_createInstance is for Cocoa implementors, and gives them low-level access to the process. API users should use alloc, which presumably uses class_createInstance or something like it.

Answer (score 2):

One is a function, the other is a method.  The function, by virtue of being a function, cannot be overloaded.  The method, (since it's a method) could conceivably be implemented in a different manner.

For example, since some classes in Cocoa (collections, for example) are class clusters, it's possible that they override `+alloc` to implement custom behavior.  You could not do that with when using a function.